# Why parented to bone object has offset in local space?

Tags: bones, constraints, parent

1. *Sphere* empty is a bone's Сhild (origin is not cleared for it).
2. *Cube* empty has *CopyLocation* constraint set to local space of *Sphere* empty.

[image]

**Now *Cube* has some offset, it is equal to bone's length. But why is it here, if Sphere empty stays right in the world origin**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To remove offset from relation:**

1. Clear origin for child object, <kbd>ALT O</kbd> (translation only) or clear parent inverse, <kbd>ALT P</kbd> (translation+rotation)
2. In bone's options enable *Relative Parenting*

[image]